Add language version option unavailable
Using Sitecore 10.1.3.
I have created 3 roles:

MyProject Reader - member of Sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
MyProject Editor - member of Sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing
MyProject Approver - member of Sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing

I have assigned Language:Read & Language:Write for all these roles to this item - /system/Languages/English
Created a new user and assigned these roles. When I login as the new user, the "Add version" is available in the top ribbon but not in the dropdown.


Hey as per your screenshot, you are opening Language dropdown where you are having option for adding Language. If you open last dropdown, there you will have option for adding version .
I have followed same step as above and I CAN see Add Version option in dropdown


Version item resides on the Core Database in the below path:
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Versions/Add Version


Can you check if the user has access to the above item and once the user has access, then they should be able to see the 'Add version' button under the version number dropdown.

Hope this helps!!!
